# Check ctags set in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

I have used

> :sets tags=./tags

to set the tags in vimrc. What would be the vim command to see the tags set in the vim environment.

Comment: Won't `set tags?` show it?

Comment: Are you trying to see the value of the `tags` settings? Or the all the tags that vim can jump to right now?

Comment: Thanks @svlasov. I was looking for a command which had same functionality as "set tags"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query any vim option value by appending a question mark after its name like so:

```
 :set tags?
```

this works too

```
 :set tags
```

If you want to list all the loaded tags:

```
 :tselect
```